# Highlight row if date is in current week

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a data table for finances. I want to highlight the row if the date is in the current week:

**What it should look like:**

[image]

The current condition formatting for the yellow fill spans B5:F15 and is the following:

```
=(TODAY()-$B6) < 7
```

The problem is that this ends up coloring the entire table yellow. **Why does it do this, and how can I change the conditional formula?**

**What it actually looks like:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out the solution. I needed to check between 0 < x < 7. See below:

```
= AND(TODAY()-$B6)<=7, TODAY()-$B6)>=0)
```

This will highlight the row whose date reflects the current week.

---

Additionally, if you wish to highlight the row(s) in the current month, use the following conditional formula, and apply it to the entire table:

```
=AND(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH($B6),YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR($B6))
```

Comment: For current month try `=$B6-DAY($B6)=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())`

Comment: That does look a little cleaner, thank you! :)

Comment: This formula is *completely* wrong. I don't know why it has so many upvotes. The other answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the current week use

```
=today()-weekday(today(), 3)=$b6-weekday($b6, 3)
```

Comment: This worked for me, while the other answers did not.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I wanted to highlight 'week commencing' cells within a Gantt chart which are between a start date and end date, so I adapted the formula as such:

```
=AND(StartDate - WeekCommencing < 7, EndDate - WeekCommencing >= 0)
```